# When standby died in the postgresql synchronous way

Tags: database, postgresql, asynchronous, replication, high-availability

There are two db servers.

Integrity is important, so I set it to sync.

But the problem is when standby dies.

Is there a way to stop replication and keep the service going?

No matter how hard I look for it, there's no solution.

Comment: You might want the dba stackexchange site for this question, but I'm not entirely clear what you mean. Are you saying you want to keep the primary processing transactions WITHOUT disabling the syncrhonous replication but WITH it broken? Because that doesn't make any sense. Or do you just not know how to disable the syncrhonous commit requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You may trying setting `synchronous_commit` parameter to `local` or `off`.